# How to check if an object is NULL in Inno Setup Pascal Script?

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I am writing a pascal function using Inno setup studio which checks if an object is null and does something

so far I have:

```
XMLDocument.setProperty('SelectionLanguage', 'XPath');
XMLNode := XMLDocument.selectSingleNode(APath);
if (XMLNode=Null) then
begin
//do stuff
End
Else
//do other stuff
End
```

but I keep getting `invalid variant operation` error.

How do I check if an object is null in Inno Setup Pascal Script code?

Comment: Unassigned object refers to `nil`. `NULL` is a function which returns a `NULL` variant. So you wanted to write `if (XMLNode = nil) then`, or `if not Assigned(XMLNode) then` which does the same.

Comment: @TLama I get `Type Mistmatch` when trying to compile the code if I change it to what you suggest?

Comment: Well, let's start with telling us what is the compiler that you use. FreePascal, Delphi, or something else ? Please edit your question tags.

Comment: @TLama I am using Inno Setup Compiler. I will edit my question to make it more useful now

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For checking if a `Variant` is `NULL` use the [`VarIsNull`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_isxfunc_varisnull.htm) function:

```
if VarIsNull(XMLNode) then
```

However, in your case, the problem is little more complicated. The [`selectSingleNode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms757846(v=vs.85).aspx) method returns always a variant of type [`varDispatch`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/Interface_References#Interface_Assignment_Compatibility) whose actual data pointer points to a found XML DOM node, or to `nil` in case no such node is found. In Delphi (language in which Inno Setup Pascal Script is written) there is the [`VarIsClear`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/System.Variants.VarIsClear) function which covers also such situation. Unfortunately, it is not published in Inno Setup. You can however test this case with a statement like this:

```
if (IDispatch(XMLNode) = nil) then
```

That will get the data from the returned [`varDispatch`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/Interface_References#Interface_Assignment_Compatibility) variant and those data test for `nil`.

---

Martijn Laan added the `VarIsClear` function to Unicode version of Inno Setup in [`this commit`](https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/commit/322a0bc2fbd6a7d5573650062c6d57d8c6a069ef), so since Inno Setup 5.5.6 you can use `VarIsClear` instead of the above hack.

Comment: I think you foresaw my problem. According to the [DOM XML documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms757846(v=vs.85).aspx) selectSingleNode returns null. But for some reason my program is actually just not assigning a value if the xpath node doesn't exist therefore I actually needed `VarIsEmpty` but this is the correct answer for the question I asked. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! Well, the problem is a bit deeper. The value returned by the `selectSingleNode` call (when using late binding) is always of type `varDispatch` (even when the node is not found). Testing with `VarIsNull` or `VarIsEmpty` will fail anyway. You need to access that `varDispatch` variant value data and check if its `nil`. See the update.

Comment: Thanks for the update. In my case if I change to use IDispatch I get `Type Mismatch` but if I use `VarIsEmpty` it actually works. i.e. in my application if the element doesnt exist I insert element else I update and display different message boxes. and `varIsEmpty` seems to work. Thanks for the info I will look further into it

Comment: That's strange. `VarIsEmpty` should not work in ANSI Inno Setup for this case either. The returned type is still `varDispatch` (tested in v.5.5.4 (a)). `VarIsEmpty` function should test only if a variant is of type `varEmpty` (which is not, so `VarIsEmpty` should return False, but it doesn't). About the type mismatch, there is some problem with `as` casting, if you write `if (IDispatch(XMLNode) = nil) then` then it works as expected (and it is the right way).

Comment: Yes `if (IDispatch(XMLNode) = nil) then` works. If this is the way you advise doing it, I will stick to it. Strange that VarIsEmpty works? Possibly a bug in the program?

Comment: If it's meaning should be same as in Delphi (and I bet that it should), then it's a bug, because as [`the reference`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/System.Variants.VarIsEmpty) (as well as the implementation which only checks if the variant type is `varEmpty`) says: *VarIsEmpty does not indicate when a Variant that represents an interface has had the interface pointer cleared* and that's exactly this case. The `VarType` returns `varDispatch` which means that the returned variant is not empty (it would return `varEmpty` if it was).

Comment: In Unicode Inno Setup it works as expected. There the `VarIsEmpty` returns correct value. But your best bet is still checking the variant type first, like `if VarType(XMLNode) = varDispatch then`. If such check fails, then the method returned something which is not a DOM node interface reference. If it succeed, then you can safely inspect the data by casting to `IDispatch`.

Comment: So, in ANSI Inno Setup you are safe to use `VarIsEmpty` for this case. It tests also if the type is `varDispatch` and data there `nil`. That's what won't work in Unicode Inno Setup though. Here is a short [`discussion`](http://news.jrsoftware.org/read/article.php?id=29337&group=jrsoftware.innosetup.code#29337) about it.